# PyQt5: QVBoxLayout: how to make three buttons as a group?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qvboxlayout

So I have made a simple PyQt5 application with a QVBoxLayout. Obviously, each button I add stretches out from one end to another and they all stack on on top of each other. How can I add buttons to QVBoxLayout that would be a group of three small buttons on my screen?

Comment: Do you have an example? A sketch of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes! I found this on the internet (can't post my code example, because I have changed it, trying to achieve what I want)
[link]http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/images/LayoutsWithoutDesigner/RunLayoutWithoutDesigner.png
the top is what I want to achieve and the three buttons under is what I achieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need a `QHBoxLayout` for your buttons, nested in a `QVBoxLayout`:

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        self.buttonsWidget = QWidget()
        self.buttonsWidgetLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.buttonsWidget)
        self.buttons = [QPushButton(c) for c in 'ABC']
        for button in self.buttons:
            self.buttonsWidgetLayout.addWidget(button)

        self.placeHolder = QWidget()
        self.placeHolder.setMinimumWidth(480)
        self.placeHolder.setMinimumHeight(320)
        self.placeHolder.setStyleSheet('* {background: red;}')

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.placeHolder)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.buttonsWidget)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: well, I have an interactive screen there, so the buttons have to go under it (so QVBoxLayout) otherwise they will go on the side of that screen

Comment: I have a vtk renderwindowinteractor there, and I need three buttons to go under it. So far I could only achieve three long buttons directly under it with H layout or small ones on its side with V layout. But I want to have three small ones under it

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot, added to my code and it worked

Answer (score -1):

To ensure that the elements are not stretched, you can use a special
QSpacerItem element.

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        btn_layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
        # !!!
        btn_layout.addItem(Qt.QSpacerItem(0, 0, Qt.QSizePolicy.Expanding, Qt.QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        btn1 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 1")
        btn2 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 2")
        btn3 = Qt.QPushButton("Button 3")

        btn_layout.addWidget(btn1)
        btn_layout.addWidget(btn2)
        btn_layout.addWidget(btn3)

        table = Qt.QTableWidget()
        table.setRowCount(5)
        table.setColumnCount(5)
        layout.addWidget(table)
        layout.addLayout(btn_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image]